# Magento not rebuilding product thumbnail cache?

Tags: php, magento, caching, image-resizing

Alright, so I implemented an adaptiveResize module (https://github.com/wearefarm/magento-adaptive-resize).  I think I have it installed correctly.

I am actually using large "thumbnails" as product images on my site because it seemed the easiest way to get multiple images per product.  So altering in product images I am altering the thumbnails.

Okay, so I go to app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml and change the thumbnail's resize function to adaptiveResize.  But now all those images are loading as the default Magento placeholder.  Boo.  Changing back to regular resize fixes the problem.

I renamed media/catalog/product/cache to force the site to create a new cache folder.  It has done so, but inside its created an image and small_image folder, but no thumbnail folder.

My .htaccess file has memory limit set to 512M.  I don't seem to have a php.ini file (or I don't know where it is...) but there is a php.ini.sample, which also has memory set to 512M.

Any ideas?  Are the photos just too large?

site is at cart.oldfloridian.com.  Category images also are acting up after implementing this module (http://learntipsandtricks.com/blog/magento/121/How-to-resize-Magento-e-Commerce-category-images) - perhaps the same cache issue?

Answer (score 3):

I just installed and it works fine, make sure you media/* is 777 and go to magento cache in admin panel and click Flush Catalog Images Cache

It looks like permission issue.

then

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->adaptiveResize(250,380);
```

Comment: Isn't it though not good to have a folder like media 777?  Or do you only set it like that temporarily then switch back to 755?

Comment: Okay, so I tried that (had before under different circumstances) and no change.  Looks like media/catalog/product/cache is rebuilt, but it is again only building "images" and "small images", no thumbnails.  Does media need to be set 777 recursively for all subfolders?  The folders in the chain down to the cache are all 777, but not every subfolder in media.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure PHP "GD" graphics module is installed. Magento uses it to create the thumbnails. Type in your shell:

```
php5 -m
```

See if gd is in the list. If it's not, install it and restart apache by typing this in your shell:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
sudo apachectl restart
```

[There are more comprehensive instructions at this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-or-add-php-gd-support-to-apache/).

Answer (score 0):

Flakerim was right about flushing the Catalog Images Cache, but omitted also flushing your browser cache. That did the trick for me.

You don't have to be careful with any folders in var/ so you can always safely run

```
rm -Rf var/cache/* var/generation/*
```